# Removing errors in xcode ios

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
     return self;
 }
```

I am having this error " no visible @interface for uiviewcontroller declares the selector initwithstyle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make this as a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

if you want to use existing file then change this in you .h

```
@interface YourClassName : UITableViewCell
```

Or, you can just create a new class as a subclass of `UITableViewCell`

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The method needs to be visible in the interface to be accessible.

To do this, put the method name in the header file:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style;
```

Comment: didn't work ! I am using .xib files not story board.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class subclass of **UITableViewCell** Not **UIViewController**

Answer (score 0):

You should have to change your Superclass in Headerfile to UITableViewController.

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
```

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style

is an initializer from UITableViewController, not from UITableViewCell.